# How do you store QR codes in Android Pay aka Google Wallet

Tags: java, android, ios

I am building a webpage that will generate a QR code for consumers and currently it has the ability for the QR code to be stored in Apple Wallet aka passbook, however, the people from Android Pay (Google Wallet) are saying that they don't support that.

has anybody had experience with having a QR code (not the image just the code since I believe it can generate the image) and then store the code in Google Wallet ?

A use case can be something like buying tickets on Fandango for a movie or a show to some event and storing the QR code in your Google wallet to be used when you enter the venue.

thanks

Comment: If you are referring to loyalty/rewards cards - this may help: https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/guides/loyalty/get-started

Answer (score 1):

Android Pay (Google Wallet) is just a payment mechanism and doesn't have the same features that Apple Wallet/Passbook has. Like the people from Android Pay have already told you, this isn't something that they support right now.

If you want somewhere to store QR codes and barcodes on your Android phone, maybe google drive or some 3rd party android app can do it for you.

Comment: thanks.  yes this is what the google API team also concluded.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a recent update, Google now supports adding things like passports, cards, etc to Google Wallet.

At the time of writing this it doesn't let you add plain QR Codes though, so you will have to request an issuer ID and create a Wallet pass in your backend.
I hope this might change in the future but currently it's how it is.

Read more in the [official guide](https://developers.google.com/wallet)

Comment: Hello thanks for taking the time to let me know :-)

Answer (score 1):

Generic QR codes are new supported, see [generic passes](https://developers.google.com/wallet/generic) in the API docs.

See this step-by-step [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/add-to-wallet-web#0) for getting started.